# Live linux cd's with TOR

Tags: linux

I've looked on distrowatch for linux live distros with tor, but not all distros are shown. I know "Birds Linux" live cd has tor, but isn't on distrowatch. Can anyone suggest other distros with tor, which arn't on distrowatch, or a list of linux distros with tor?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would want to use Tails, which is a live version of Linux that runs from a thumb drive that runs Tor by default. https://tails.boum.org. You didn't mention in your question if you had already seen this and discarded it as an option, and I don't want to assume you are are aware of it already.

From the site:

> Tails is a live operating system that you can start on almost any computer from a USB stick or a DVD.
>
> It aims at preserving your privacy and anonymity, and helps you to:
>
> - use the Internet anonymously and circumvent censorship;
>     all connections to the Internet are forced to go through the Tor network;
> - leave no trace on the computer you are using unless you ask it explicitly;
>     use state-of-the-art cryptographic tools to encrypt your files, emails and instant messaging.

Answer (score 0):

I use tails and tor-RAMdisk distributions.